# Need to combine (add together) values in a table based on data in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to solve an issue and have ended up on the rocks...

Data looks like this:

```
ID, Product_Code, Amount
123, Sandwich_Ham, 2.50
234, Sandwich_Egg, 2.75
123, Sandwich_Mustard, 0.50
123, Coffee, 1.50
456, Sandwich_Beef, 3.75
234, Water, 1.25
456, Sandwich_Horseradish, 0.75
456, Beer, 4.75
```

Data to be returned to a Crystal Report.

```
ID, Product_Code, Amount
123, Sandwich_Ham, 3.00
123, Coffee, 1.50
234, Sandwich_Egg, 2.75
234, Water, 1.25
456, Sandwich_Beef, 4.50
456, Beer, 4.75
```

As you can see in the example above, I need to add together (sum) the amount column for products that have match on the beginning of the Product_Code field and return just one row with the total amount in the Amount column (instead of the two) All other rows pass-through as-is.

For a given ID, there are only two rows that would have matching prefix (in effect only one condiment allowed per sandwich), max one sandwich per person.

The Crystal report filters by ID and has to display every line for a given ID, so no way I can just sum the values in CR. (I've tried.)

I created a scalar-valued function that returns the total amount when passed an ID, but can't figure out how to get that to would for an entire table. Based on my reading, a table-valued function won't help.

My thought is I could write a stored procedure to loop through the table, call the scalar function to handle the case where a product code begins with 'Sandwich_' and write everything out to a temp table. I would use a view to call the stored procedure and return the rows from the temp table. Then modify the report in CR to use the view. Performance could be a big issue with this plus it seems to rather complex for dealing with a 'small change' to an existing report.

Any suggestions on other methods for solving this (before I go another rat hole...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT` to get the grouping and then do a simple `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('_', Product_Code) = 0 THEN Product_Code
                ELSE LEFT(Product_Code, CHARINDEX('_', Product_Code) - 1)
              END
    FROM #Tbl
)
SELECT
    ID,
    Product_Code = MAX(Product_Code),
    Amount = SUM(Amount)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY
    ID, grp
ORDER  BY Id;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/596660)</kbd>

Comment: That works! I had to make one small change:

`Product_Code = MAX(Product_Code)`
to
`Product_Code = MIN(Product_Code)`.

'MIN' was returning Sandwich_Mustard instead of Sandwich_Ham. 

Thanks very much. I was making that way too complicated.

Comment: That should have read:

'**MAX**' was returning Sandwich_Mustard instead of Sandwich_Ham.

Comment: I gave this a +1 but my rep points are too for it show. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this as Select in CR

```
Select id, case when charIndex('_', product_Code) > 0 
                then left(product_Code, charIndex('_', product_Code)
                else product_Code end ProductCategory, 
       sum (Amount) totalAmt
From myTable
Group By id, case when charIndex('_', product_Code) > 0 
                then left(product_Code, charIndex('_', product_Code)
                else product_Code end
```

Comment: I see what you are trying there, looks like it would work. How would I add it to CR? I'm on Version 2008 and  I don't see an option to use SQL syntax in a CR Select formula.

Comment: I'm not really current on CR, last time I used it was many years ago, but as I recall, you can specify a SQL expression to execute to generate the data resultset to drive the report, no? If not, put this snippet into a Stored proc and drive CR from that stored proc ?

Comment: I can't find a way of putting SQL code into CR, I build the query using CR script syntax and it generates the SQL from that. I tried your code example in SSMS but it only returns one product code. The CTE method posted by Felix works, so I'll go with that. Thanks for your help.